# Slicing non-homogeneous 2D list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This snippet:

```
import numpy as np

l = [[[1, 2], 3], [[4, 5], 6]]
a = np.array(l, dtype=object)
print(a[:, -1:])
```

produces:

```
[[3]
 [6]]
```

Why does the similar slicing on `l` fail?

```
print(l[:, -1:])
...
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Comment: Because vanilla lists simply don't support the tuple (multi-dimensional) slicing that numpy's data structures do.

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Good to know. Can you make an answer out of your comment?

Comment: Try [[x[1]] for x in l] or [x[1] for x in l] depending on how the result should be represented

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[[x[1]] for x in l]
```

or

```
[x[1] for x in l]
```